# How could I specify a conditional compilation symbol within a MonoDevelop 2.8 project template (.xpt.xml)?

Tags: compilation, monodevelop, symbols, project-template

Something similar to (picked from a .csproj)

```
<DefineConstants>DEBUG; ANDROID</DefineConstants>
```

Answer (score 4):

Right click the project, go to Options -> Build -> Compiler. You can add the constants where it says Define Symbols.